# Jquery CSS change not working for pseudo-element :before

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

Hello I am trying to update a font awesome icon (that is generated by CSS

```
$( '.fa-chevron-right:before' ).css("color", 'red' );
```

The same code in CSS works fine...

```
.fa-chevron-right:before{color:red}
```

My HTML code that it is updating...

```
<li class="separator fa fa-chevron-right">some text</li>
```